# How to produce correct endless socket connection?

Tags: python, sockets, cycle

I need to produce endless socket connections, which can be broke only with 1KeyboardInterupt1 or special word.

When I start both programs in different IDEs, the sender asks to input the message. But only the first message sends to the server and all the others don't.

I need to produce an endless cycle, where all inputs are sent to the server on print.

The server part:

```
import socket

s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.bind(('127.0.0.1', 8888))
s.listen(5)
while True:
    try:
        client, addr = s.accept()
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        s.close()
        break
    else:
        res = client.recv(1024)
        print(addr, 'says:', res.decode('utf-8'))
```

And the client:

```
import socket

s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)

s.connect(('127.0.0.1', 8888))
while True:    
    com = input('Enter the message: ')
    s.send(com.encode())   
    print('sended')
    if com == 'exit':
        s.close()
        break
```

I tried to do this on the client:

```
import socket

while True:
    s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    s.connect(('127.0.0.1', 8888))    
    com = input('Enter the message: ')
    s.send(com.encode())   
    print('sended')
    s.close()
    if com == 'exit':
        break
```

But this way needs to create a socket, make connection and close socket every iteration.
Is there the way how to do what I described above with only one socket initialization?

Comment: Your server reads one line from each connection, then goes back to wait for another socket.  You might want to spin off a thread to handle each new accepted socket.  Or, if this is the basis for production code, take a look at the `twisted` module.  It has great examples of production quality socket code.

Comment: In Python the easiest way is to start a thread.

Answer (score 0):

The s.close() must be out of the while loop.